# transition probabilty of being in bottom row is 1/6

Tags: transition, probability, chain, markov

I'm currently studying transition probabilities using Markov chain diagrams which I thought I understood. However I'm now required to find the probabilities of being in the bottom row of a 3x3 grid is 1/6 and the probability of being in the middle row is 2/6 which has completely thrown me! Any advice would be appreciated!

The question is >Find transition probabilities
 between the cells such that the probability to be in the bottom 
row (cells 1,2,3) is 1/6. The probability to be in the middle row is 2/6.

Comment: Where is the current position? Markov chains are all about probability from x to y, not just probability of y.

Comment: @EliSadoff The position could be from any of the squares of the 3x3 grid where you can only move to an adjacent sqaure